# what's the difference between using 'single quotes' or not in find command

Tags: shell, find, quoting

```
find ~/ -name *test.txt
find ~/ -name '*test.txt'
```

I need to construct an example where the first form fails but the second still works.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The quotes protect the contents from shell wildcard expansion. Run that command (or even simpler just `echo *test.txt` in a directory with a `footest.txt` file and then one without any files that end in `test.txt` and you will see the difference.

```
$ ls
a  b  c  d  e
$ echo *test.txt
*test.txt
$ touch footest.txt
$ echo *test.txt
footest.txt
```

The same thing will happen with find.

```
$ set -x
$ find . -name *test.txt
+ find . -name footest.txt
./footest.txt
$ find . -name '*test.txt'
+ find . -name '*test.txt'
./footest.txt
$ touch bartest.txt
+ touch bartest.txt
$ find . -name *test.txt
+ find . -name bartest.txt footest.txt
find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]
$ find . -name '*test.txt'
+ find . -name '*test.txt'
./bartest.txt
./footest.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr version

You are passing a string literal to the command/program, just like double-quotes but differ that single-quotes prevent variable and wildcard expansion while double-quotes expand them in to the string literal.

Example:

```
$ export MY_VAR=my_string
$ echo "$MY_VAR"
my_string
$ echo '$MY_VAR'
$MY_VAR
```

The same applies to wildcards

EDIT:

An example like the one you asking is IMO impossible, because any literal that the second command matches will be inevitable matched by the wildcard in the first command.

Comment: Thank you! I got the point between "" and ''. How about the question I mentioned above?

Comment: There's no wildcard expansion inside double-quotes. Your last sentence doesn't make sense either.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the other answers, `zsh`, `fish` and `(t)csh` are more helpful here in that they can help you show your mistake before it becomes a problem:

If there's no `*test.txt` file in the current directory:

```
zsh$ find . -name *test.txt
zsh: no matches found: *test.txt
```

```
fish> find . -name *test.txt
fish: No matches for wildcard '*test.txt'.
find . -name *test.txt
             ^
```

```
tcsh> find . -name *test.txt
find: No match.
```

`fish` and `zsh` are correct in making it clear that it's the *shell* (not `find`) that is complaining here, while `tcsh`'s error is misleading. (tcsh only reports `No match` however if *all* the globs on the command line fail to match. If some match and some don't, those that don't will expand to themselves like in Bourne-like shells).

With `bash`, you can obtain the same behaviour with:

```
$ shopt -s failglob
$ find . -name *test.txt
bash: no match: *test.txt
```

Comment: `failglob` is present at least as far back as bash 3.2.25 (CentOS 5) so I'm not sure that counts as "recent" at this point.

Answer (score -3):

In the first case, the argument `*test.txt` is considered an operator of the `find` command itself whereas with quotes, the argument `*test.txt` will be considered a parameter to a switch of `find`.

If you have more than one text files with the `.txt` extension in your current directory, the following will fail as find will not see a `*.txt` argument:

```
find . -name *.txt
```

Whereas this will succeed:

```
find . -name '*.txt'
```

Comment: That's wrong, the correct answer is the one from @etan reisner, it's a case of shell expansion before it even reaches to find.

Comment: Ok, I realize that.